# startx for single application fails because of xterm

Tags: linux, xorg, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run epiphany directly using startx on a raspberry pi. The idea is to run epiphany in kiosk mode pointing to a website. The command that I would like to run is:

```
startx epiphany -a --profile ~/.profile google.com
```

It fails. And yes, I have tested the command in a normal x session and it works perfectly. Here is the error:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: bad command line option "-a"
```

So I started to simplify the problem. The following works and I get a browser:

```
startx epiphany
```

BUT if I try to add any arguments to epiphany, xorg fails to start. E.g, the following command fails:

```
startx epiphany google.com
```

The error is slightly different but pretty much the same:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: Explicit shell already was /usr/bin/epiphany
/usr/bin/xterm: bad command line option "google.com"
```

The above is then followed by the proper usage for xterm as if I was starting xterm with google.com as an argument and not epiphany.

It's as if xterm is somehow reading the epiphany arguments as its own arguments. I tried using double and single quotes around the epiphany command but xterm still throws the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page for xinit (which startx uses the same arguments as),

> Both  the  client  program  name and the server program name must begin
>          with a slash (/) or a period (.).  Otherwise, they are  treated  as  an
>          arguments to be appended to their respective startup lines.  This makes
>          it possible to add arguments (for example,  foreground  and  background
>          colors) without having to retype the whole command line.

So `startx epiphany` and `startx epiphany -a --profile ~/.profile google.com` are actually passing "epiphany" as the first argument to the default client (in this case, xterm). To run Epiphany as the client (and thus be able to specify arguments for Epiphany), you need to pass the entire path to startx:

```
startx /usr/bin/epiphany [arguments to epiphany]
```

Since Epiphany may be located somewhere else (e.g., on my Fedora 22 machine it's at /bin/epiphany), you may want to use which:

```
startx `which epiphany` [arguments to epiphany]
```